# What was the Lena River Delta U-boat base in the Arctic used for?

Tags: world-war-two, war, nazi-germany, russia

In 1963 the body of a German navy NCO was found in Neelova Gulf with the remnants of his uniform and rifle ammunition.

In 1985 Soviet helicopter pilot Peter Statsyukom discovered a small complex of five underground Nazi bunkers in the delta of the Lena River in the Siberian Arctic.

Article in Russian:
[What did the Nazis build in the mouth of Lena?](http://www.sentstory.ru/ob-arktike/chto-stroili-natsisty-v-uste-leny/)

[Lena Delta](http://www.rusnature.info/zap/133-1.jpg)

[Lena Delta cliffs](http://www.lhnet.org/assets/Landscape-database/Lena-Delta/_resampled/resizedimage450338-lenapillars06.jpg)

Apparently these artificial caves were built into a large rocky outcrop and blasted out with explosives. Nearby there was a 200m concrete jetty built linked by a small tramway to the storage caves. These storage bunkers sheltered 250 German manufactured fuel drums.

Inside an accommodation bunker they also found Nazi era coins, German naval badges and buttons. There had always been wartime tales amongst the indigenous Yakut people about mysterious men called chuchuna dressed in black spotted in the Bykovskaya Duct area between 1940-42.

According to some accounts when the intact wreck of a German U-boat, U-534 was raised in the Baltic by a wealthy private individual, amongst her soaked papers were orders at the end of WWII to sail to the Lena Delta.

My question is what was the base used for?

The nearest U-Boat base was at Narvik in Norway. DISTANCE FROM Narvik to Tokyo was 7,540nm, easily within the 13,450nm range of an IXC40 class Uboat

Was it in support of U-boat operations to Japan or to refuel flying boat operations to Japan, or for espionage/reconnaissance flights deep into the soviet rear?

Does anybody know and if so please could you identify sources?

[OPERATION WUNDERLAND
August 1942](http://dracobooks.com/Operation-Wunderland-1942.html)  my speculation is that the LENA BASE could have been built by the GERMAN Merchant Raider Komet, disguiset as a SOVIET ice breaker

[Komet voyage to Japan via the Soviet ARCTIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_auxiliary_cruiser_Komet) 
Nor should we forget U362 was sunk in the Laptev Sea at 89.27 deg East:

[image: U362 SUNK]

Comment: Was there any base at all? Sounds like a question for [skeptics](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/). Google search didn't bring anything other than unconfirmed theories published in local newspapers.

Comment: Before you ask *why* this base existed, [it needs to be established that it existed at all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question).

Comment: Related: [Who deposited German fuel drums on a Japanese air base](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/14265)

Comment: @DevSolar: yep, and the answer is pretty much the same.

Comment: THERE IS PLENTYOF EVIDENCE available online in Rissian news media for example here:http://www.sentstory.ru/ob-arktike/chto-stroili-natsisty-v-uste-leny/

Comment: EVIDENCE in Russian news:http://www.sentstory.ru/ob-arktike/chto-stroili-natsisty-v-uste-leny/            

" Nazis penetrated  the mouth of the Lena River , where a secret base was barrels marked WHERMACHT were discovered in 1963, . Local residents gladly accepted these "bounty", but were not particularly interested in their origin. Only in the 1970s when helicopter pilots of BAM discovered & inspected. Invisible  facilities built beside the canal on a flat island, sheltered by a high rock.

Eyewitnesses said they found a 200m concrete pier on the left bank of Bykovskaya duct

Comment: Comments are not for discussion. Comments identify issues; edit the question to address the issues and the flag the comments for dismissal.  In this case, the question should contain _all_ the evidence for the existence of the base.

Comment: I think there are the makings of a good question here, *but* there are also some misleading facts. Firstly, one of the images to the "Lena Delta" doesn't work -- but the name references the Lena Pillars which are not at the delta but far upstream. Further, the second image looks weird and though the Lena Delta is nestled (to a degree) within some hills, the lie of the land is quite different. Second, the Google Earth image has nothing to do with Lena but is of a place mid-way between the Khatanga and Yenisei. Is this meant to be the base's real location? If so, why talk about the Lena Delta?

Answer (score 12):

## tl;dr

No such base has ever existed.

## Let's look at the map

The ["port distance"](https://sea-distances.org/) between Kiel and Archangel is 1951 nautical miles, between Kiel and Murmansk - 1584 nautical miles.

The [air distance](http://www.distancefromto.net/) between Murmansk and Tiksi (Lena delta) is 1744.66 nmi.

Yes, a [German Type IX submarine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_Type_IX_submarine) with a range of 12knmi can go there and back. Can it actually carry there concrete, fuel drums, workers, heavy equipment &c &c &c? Not really.

Moreover, one look at the [map](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Murmansk,+Murmansk+Oblast,+Russia/Tiksi,+Sakha+Republic,+Russia) is enough to realize that a Krigsmarine base there would serve no purpose. It is too far to be used against the [Arctic convoys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arctic_convoys_of_World_War_II). There are no targets in the area. Pacific is also too far. Add to this the harsh climate (to put it mildly - ocean actually freezes and the base is unreachable 9 months of the year) and the question becomes moot.

## Yes, but the rumors are so persistent!

My *guess* is that it all started with [oil drums](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/14265/1979).
USSR swiped in Germany everything if could carry.
They probably took the fuel drums and brought them to Tiksi (and many other places).
Some of them might have been stolen by the locals, who then, quite naturally, [claim to have fished them out of the river](http://fisechko.ru/100vel/vtor_mir/98.html).
Then the rumor mill takes over - someone would claim to have seen Nazi coins or uniforms or submarine pens...

**At any rate, I think the Lena base is as real as the [Secret Nazi Base in Antarctica](http://www.popularmechanics.com/military/a25672/nazi-antarctica-base-debunked/) or [on the Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Sky).**

**PS**: Don't confuse this mythical base with [automatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weather_Station_Kurt) and [manned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Haudegen) weather stations. Lena delta is too far to be useful as such.

Comment: There's also a Nazi base on the moon. On the backside of it, if I remember correctly. I think I saw a documentary on it once;-)

Comment: @coderworks yes, it was built there for the nazis by the Mossad on orders of the CIA :)

Comment: There were small weather stations by the German Navy or Air Force in the arctic. I **haven't** heard about any on Soviet soil.

Comment: @o.m. given the extent of German occupation of Europe, they would have several such within their own territory, which included northern Norway.

Comment: @jwenting, they did go beyond the perimeter of their conventional military occupation, e.g. to Svalbard. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Haudegen

Comment: the only person confused is you: German type IXC Uboat range was 13,450 nmi (24,910 km; 15,480 mi) at 10 knots Distance  from the uboat depot at Narvik to to Tokyo 7,540nm, therefore distance was not an issue except in your imagination

Comment: The unsubstantiated theory that looted Nazi  fuel drums reached the town of Tiksi does not explain who built a 200m concrete peir  adjoined by 5 caves concealing Nazi coins

Comment: @user2357: Regarding this pier, as this seems to be the most important part of the evidence, what imagery, locations, etc do you have? None of the links mention or show such a pier existing.

Comment: A [Type XB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_X_submarine) would be a more probable choice for such a mission than a Type IX: greater range, designed as a minelayer, and actually used as a cargo sub.